# How to disable dialog and other accesses for another app, optionally with root

Tags: root-access, permissions

I'm looking for a way to prevent a certain app from showing any dialogs, on a rooted commercial device running android 11 or 10. Further, I'm also interested in intercepting its location data requests and return a dummy.

The first thing that comes to my mind is to disassemble the app, dig & modify the relevant pieces, pack and reinstall. However, this complicates future updates. I think with root permission, I should be able to intercept the system service call, aka tell the daemon to do nothing or something else when requested (not sure if this is the right naming; I come from desktop/server linux). If the described functionality is possible to implement, I wonder if it's going to be custom module for the system, a modified system service daemon, or an app runing with sudo?

Any suggestion in general is greatly appreciated. I'm digging around in the documentations and too lost to figure out if some or all of the ideas are actually implausible. Thank you.

Comment: "*I think with root permission, I should be able to intercept the system service call*". Theoretically yes. You can use Xposed to hook into system APIs. But it's not very simple. You'll need to write an app which interacts with Xposed and takes control of the callbacks for the required APIs (related to `AlertDialog` in your case).

Comment: @IrfanLatif Thank you, this is very helpful. I have a related question: would it be easier to implement the app, if I choose to intercept/disable _all_ dialogs, instead of dialogs from that one app in question? I imagine the latter requires checking with some app identifiers, but I'm hopping that the former _might_ be a simple toggling (e.g. like `systemd disable dialog` to drop the service, or altering a magical global variable).

Comment: No. In Android there's no system-wide service to manage dialogs. A [`Dialog`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog) is a component of the App's UI ([`Activity`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity), to be more precise), and every app creates its Dialogs on its own. There's a possibility that some apps create their own dialogs, not using system APIs. You can't control them anyway. But mostly developers prefer to use framework APIs, which you can try to intercept. But even then, apps are highly likely to crash. That's why it's not simple, as I said.

Comment: By the way your query sounds more like development-oriented which is off-topic here.

Comment: @IrfanLatif Thank you so much, I'll stop here. Now I have a much better idea about what docs to look out for. If you post the comments as an answer I'm more than willing to accept it.